# Bash - creating heredoc dynamically results "here-document at line XX delimited by end-of-file"

Tags: bash

```
$ export VAR=xx
$ echo -e "$(cat <<'EOF'\n$VAR\nEOF\n)"
```

Result is:

```
bash: warning: here-document at line 117 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOFn$VARnEOFn')
bash: warning: here-document at line 117 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOFn$VARnEOFn')
bash: warning: here-document at line 1 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOFn$VARnEOFn')
```

What am I doing wrong? Why EOFn$VARnEOFn? Where is my '\n' interpolation?

Comment: A `\n` inside a double quoted string simply evaluates to `n`, because `\n` is not a specific escape sequence. Therefore, `echo -e` (which would understand \n) never sees the backslash.

Comment: So single-quotes gixes me \n properly interpolated, and double quotes gives ne varuable interpolated. How can I combine it? Double backslashes doesn't work.

Comment: You can't. Look at my answer. You need the delimiter on a line of its own.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do the `echo` in such a convoluted way, but from a viewpoint of syntax, this would work:

```
echo "$(cat <<EOF
$VAR
EOF
)"
```

Note that the here-delimiter must be on a line of its own, and you don't want to use single quotes, if you want the variable to be expanded.

Comment: I can't use real newlines, it's part of single-lite script.

Comment: What do you mean by "single-lite"? If you want to write everything into a single line, than don't use a here document.

Comment: This is part of gttlab-ci.yml file. And I need to use heredoc because my variables can have newlines and quotes.

Comment: The **content** of your variables should not matter. A variable can contain everything. It may matter if you are using the variable in an odd way. A heredoce is really mostly an aid for making data easier to read. You can do everything you can do with a heredoc also without one - you just have to do it properly. I suggest you try an approach without a heredoc, if you get stuck, ask a new question and show your attempt.

Comment: it is mattter beacuse I creating command line which I intend  to eval.

Comment: Really looks like an XY-problem to me: Whenever you want to create a command line, which you want to `eval`, it is quite probable that a better alternative exist. But for that matter, if you want bash to turn a `n` into a newline inside a string, you have to use the special quoting `$'\n'`". Try it first with an `echo` to get some feeling for this (i.e. `echo ABC$'DEF\nGHI'JKL`)

Comment: If you're trying to create eval-safe inputs then `printf %q` is what you're looking for.